# What word am I thinking of when you're careful what you say?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am trying to think of a word you would use instead of the word 'careful' in this sentence:

> "I'll be _________ [careful] what I say"

Take the example of when you're talking about adult content in front of young children - you would use limited vocabulary.

I'm not thinking of the word 'cautious' or 'subdued' or 'limited vocabulary'.

What advanced word could be used instead of careful and not listed above?

Comment: You could select any appropriate word from this list of synonyms of 'diplomatic'  at [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/diplomatic?s=t).

Comment: You simply will ***watch*** what you say..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word you are thinking of is ***circumspect***.

OED sense 2a, defines the adjective circumspect (noun: circumspection) as:

> . Of persons: Watchful on all sides, attentive to everything,
>   cautious, heedful of all circumstances that may affect action or
>   decision.

It derives from the French *circonspect* (Latin - *circumspectus*)

Examples:

> 1430   Lydgate tr. Hist. Troy ii. xvi,   Circumspect in all his
>   gouernance.
>
> a1513   R. Fabyan New Cronycles Eng. & Fraunce (1516) I. ccxlvi. f.
>   clxviii,   Which in all his faytes is so circumspecte.
>
> 1542   A. Borde Compend. Regyment Helth xxiii. sig. L.iv,   Sanguyne
>   men..must be cyrcumspect in eatynge of theyr meate.
>
> 1597   Shakespeare Richard III iv. ii. 32   High reaching Buckingham
>   growes circumspect .
>
> 1624   J. Smith Gen. Hist. Virginia iv. 147   This will make us more
>   circumspect.
>
> a1727   I. Newton Chronol. Anc. Kingdoms Amended (1728) ii. 260
>   Herodotus was circumspect and faithful in his narrations.
>
> 1847   W. H. Prescott Hist. Conquest Peru I. iii. iv. 382   The wild
>   passes..practicable..for the sure and circumspect mule.
>
> 1881   W. Besant & J. Rice Chaplain of Fleet I. iii. 38,   I was to be
>   circumspect in my behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I do like the word "mindful" to suggest that one is carefully, thoughtfully, and deliberately choosing words and actions.

"I'll be mindful of what I say."

(My first post on the forum and I manage to wade into the Oxford comma debate.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that in such a case you are being *discreet.*

[A couple of definitions](http://www.wordnik.com/words/discreet) of *discreet* are:

> *adj.* marked by, exercising, or showing prudence and wise self-restraint in speech and behavior; circumspect.
>
> *adj.* Possessed of discernment, especially in avoiding error or evil, and in the adaptation of means to ends; prudent; sagacious; judicious; not rash or heedless; cautious.

An example sentence: *Because the children were within earshot, she was discreet in her description of the R-rated movie she saw over the weekend.*

Answer (score 0):

> "I'll be ***measured*** with what I say"

ODO:

> **[measured](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/measured)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** (**of speech** or writing) **carefully considered**; deliberate **and restrained**.
>
> ‘When he talks, it is with quiet, carefully measured sentences.’

Answer (score -1):

***Cagey*** -- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cagey)

> (adj.) unwilling to give information:
>   *He was very cagey about what happened at the meeting.*